# VPN connects but my browsers and messenger don't connect

Tags: internet, vpn

I have no problem VPN into work. 
As of last night, everything worked fine.

But as of this A.M., none of my browsers connect and Microsoft Messenger will not connect.

I did nothing, but had a pending a OSX update. I rebooted.. Still no internet.

All network connections working, clearly, since VPN works. Its how I am doing this post now, is via VPN and remote desktopping to work computer.

This just showed up as of this morning not working.
I renewed DHCP, etc.. but cannot ping anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

"All network connections working, clearly, since VPN works. Its how I am doing this post now, is via VPN and remote desktopping to work computer."

Or not.. since you can't connect without the VPN :)

We would need more info about the setup, but regardless of the OS, I would say this is some proxy config or the gateway/firewall is blocking it...

If you "trace route" to some internet address what do you get? and what about the openvpn IP? If you're able to reach that but nothing else some firewall must be in place.